# How to set a tab active when the nav bar is in the application template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple nav bar like so:

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li><a href="<%= index_url %>">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="<%= users_url %>">Users</a></li>
</ul>
```

Which is part of the `application.html.erb` file in a rails project. I would like the `class="active"` attribute to be set on whatever the current page is, however this is complicated since the nav bar is in the template that yields to the rest of the app with `<%= yield %>`. How can I reliably set the active tab based on what page I'm loading?

*...javascript removed because it was distracting from the actual question.*

To clarify:

Rails loads the `application.html.erb` which renders everything up to and including this nav before calling `<%= yield %>` and rendering whatever view I'm loading.

I want the "Users" tab to have the `class="active"` when I'm displaying the users/index.html.erb file, or the users/show.html.erb (basically anything from the user model) is there a proper rails way to do this?

I know I could move the nav bar to each model's view template and manually set the active class, but that's not very "DRY".

Comment: Your current code removes and then adds the class to the element clicked only - you probably mean `$(".nav > li").removeClass("active")` to remove the class from all `li`s first.

Comment: Ok, so my javascript wasn't right, but my original question still remains, how can I change the active class on a link after the nav bar has been loaded (by the application template). As soon as I set a class and the click goes through it will load the new page and clear the class setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not exactly what you're looking for, but I typically just write a quick helper named "tab" that lets me set a variable into my view for the tab, and then use conditionals to set up the class on the tabs.

```
# Helper
def tab(value)
  @page_tab = value
end

# View
<% tab "about" %>

# Layout    
<ul class="nav">
   <li><a href="<%= index_url %>" <%= class=\"active\" if @page_tab == "home" %>>Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#about" <%= class=\"active\" if @page_tab == "about" %>>About</a></li>
   <li><a href="<%= users_url %>" <%= class=\"active\" if @page_tab == "users" %>>Users</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I like this solution, but it appears not to work anymore in Rails 3.2. This <%= class=\"active\" if @page_tab == "home" %> just doesn't work anymore - getting syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
$(".nav > li").click(function(){
  $(this).removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Use this

```
$(".nav > li").click(function(){
  $(".nav > li").removeClass("active"); // this line will remove class active from every li
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

**Note -** This script only work on page not refreshing can be used only when on same page rather in your case will not work

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a variable in your view, e.g.

```
- @active_tab = 'dashboard'
```

and then in layout template do something like (HAML version):

```
%ul.nav
  - ['dashboard', 'reports'].each do |tab|
    %li{:class => ('active' if @active_tab == tab)}
      = link_to t('nav_'+tab), send(tab+'_path')
```